# Converting .db to .vcf

Tags: android, ruby, sqlite, type-conversion

I accidentally deleted my contacts and i don't have a backup for that now i got the contacts2.db and i am trying to covert the .db to .vcf. Now i am using Ruby to convert the file and here is what i did

```
gem install sqlite3
gem install vpim
path to contacts2-to-vcard.rb/contacts2-to-vcard.rb > contacts.vcf
```

i always says 'Access Denied.' And i set the folder to full control but whenever i run that command it change to read only, by the way i am using windows 8. Any help? Or is there a alternate why to convert .db to .vcf? TIA

Comment: Can you provide mor information? What was the result of the gem installation? Whats in `contacts2-to-vcard.rb`? Why do you want to build `contacts.vcf` via redirection and not with a `File.open`? ...

Comment: i have contacts2.db and i change it to contacts2-to-vcard.rb then i need to change the .vcf to .rb

Answer (score 2):

Yank it out of the DB (this is all in Ruby):

```
require 'sqlite3'

path_to_contactsdb_file = "/SAMPLE/PATH/TO/contacts2.db"

db = SQLite3::Database.new path_to_contactsdb_file

raw_contacts = db.execute("select _id,display_name from raw_contacts")
contacts = {}
raw_contacts.each do |x|
   contacts[x[1]] = {}
   contacts[x[1]]['rcid'] = x[0]
   contacts[x[1]]['nums'] = db.execute("select normalized_number from phone_lookup where raw_contact_id=" + x[0].to_s)
end
```

Pull it to CSV:

```
output_filepath = "/SAMPLE/EXAMPLE/FILEPATH"    

csv = ""
contacts.each do |k,v|
 csv += '"' + k + '",'
  v['nums'].each do |num|
    csv += '"' + num[0] + '",'
  end
  csv += "\n"
end

File.open(output_filepath,"w") {|file| file.write(csv) }
```

Then you can use a CSV import app, do it through Google contacts import through CSV, etc..  You can send me a fruit basket.

If it MUST be in a VCF format, then just change the output syntax of the CSV.  Look up a sample VCF file, I couldn't be bothered.

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to use Dustin van Schouwen's code to do this task. I wanted to thank him for it, first of all, and then mention a few details I needed to add/change to make it work for me:

This line:

```
db = SQLite3::Database.new path_to_contactsdb_file
```

I changed to:

```
db = SQLite3::Database.new ("contacts2.db")
```

As when using the previous one, even though it doesn't give an error, it doesn't seem to actually connect to the database (I think it creates an empty one).

The other change I needed to do was at this other line:

```
csv += '"' + k + '",
```

If "k" is nil, the code will fail, so I introduced an if (ternary syntax) to solve it, and it worked fine:

```
csv += '"' + (k == nil ? "" : k) + '",'
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late for OP sorry. I can't give tips on ruby anyway.

But I stumbled here when searching a solution for my own needs.
I finally came up with a python solution:
https://gitlab.com/Arnaudv6/contacts2.db-2-vcard
based on previous works documented on above page.

Please refer to "todo" section at beginning of the script
for details on what is not implemented to date.